# DiscordJS V13 Mentioning a role

Tags: discord.js

Can someone help me with these code? What I want to happen here is when an admin mentions a role, I want it to do nothing or maybe send a reply like "You mentioned a role."

My Code:

```js
let findrole = args[0];
const role = message.guild.roles.cache.get.find((r) =>
  r.name.includes(findrole)
);

if (args[0] === role) return;
```

[image: My Code Image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that by checking if there are any roles mentioned in the message. All you have to do is add:

```js
if (message.mentions.roles) { // This checks if a role was mentioned
    message.channel.send(`${message.mentions.roles.first().name} was mentioned`)
}
```

Comment: Yo, Can you help me with this one? I used your code but it somehow don't work for my code.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72047171/kick-command-discordjs-v13

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure about your other question